# haskell: 99 questions #7: heterogeneous list

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell. Currently working through [99 questions](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10), a little bit stuck on #7:

> Problem 7
>   (**) Flatten a nested list structure.
>
> Transform a list, possibly holding lists as elements into a `flat' list by replacing each list with its elements (recursively).
>
> Example in Haskell:
>
> ```
> *Main> flatten (Elem 5)
> [5]
> *Main> flatten (List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]])
> [1,2,3,4,5]
> *Main> flatten (List [])
> []
> ```

Where do `Elem` and `List` come from? What do I have to do to be able to use them in my program? (Or does the question assume that I have to define a new type for these -- if that's the answer I'll go off and reread that section of the tutorial...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are just constructor of some types, e.g.

```
data ListType a = Elem a | List [ListType a]
```

Comment: Note that ListType is a really bad name. It's actually a tree.